# Identifying correct variable type in terraform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I am using the below `gcp terraform module` to create a `gcp firewall` rule using `terraform`

https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/compute_firewall

I need some help to define the correct `data type` for `allow` argument in the firewall rule

An example of the value of the argument can be as follows

```
    fw_dst_tags                 = "http,https"   
    fw_allow   =  [{
                       protocol = "tcp"
                       ports    = ["80"]
                   }]
```

For this I have created a variable type pf `list(object)`as shown below

```
    variable "target_tags" {
         type = list
        }

    variable "allow" {
         type = list(object({
         protocol = string,
         ports    = list(string,)
       }))
      }
```

But it is failing with below error

```
Error: Unsupported argument
│
│  on ../../modules/fw/fw.tf line 12, in resource "google_compute_firewall" "main":
│   12:     allow  = var.allow
│
│ An argument named "allow" is not expected here. Did you mean to define a block of type "allow"?
```

Any help to identify the correct variable for the value of type below

```
     fw_allow   =  [{
                       protocol = "tcp"
                       ports    = ["80"]
                   }]
```

Comment: What is `fw_allow`? It is not in the docs linked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The documentation for `google_compute_firewall`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/compute_firewall) is not super clear on this, but it does mention that `allow` is a *block type* rather than a plain argument:

> The `allow` block supports:
>
> - `protocol` - (Required) The IP protocol to which this rule applies. The protocol type is required when creating a firewall rule. This value can either be one of the following well known protocol strings (tcp, udp, icmp, esp, ah, sctp, ipip, all), or the IP protocol number.
> - `ports` - (Optional) An optional list of ports to which this rule applies. This field is only applicable for UDP or TCP protocol. Each entry must be either an integer or a range. If not specified, this rule applies to connections through any port. Example inputs include: ["22"], ["80","443"], and ["12345-12349"].

Even when provider documentation isn't sufficiently clear about it, you can often assume that a particular name is a block type if it's given a singular name rather than a plural name but yet multiple objects of that type are expected. In that case, each object is represented as a separate block of that type. However, that heuristic doesn't really help in this case because `allow` is a verb rather than a noun, and so it'd work equally well as an argument name and as a block type name.

You can read more about blocks in the Terraform documentation section [Arguments and Blocks](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/syntax/configuration.html#arguments-and-blocks). For your purposes here though you're looking specifically for the syntax to dynamically declare zero or more `allow` blocks based on the number of elements in your `var.allow` value. For this you'll need [`dynamic` blocks](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/dynamic-blocks.html), which are the syntax construct for dynamically declaring multiple blocks as a sort of macro or template.

```
  dynamic "allow" {
    for_each = var.allow
    content {
      protocol = allow.value.protocol
      ports    = allow.value.ports
    }
  }
```

The above says that there should be one `allow` block generated for each element of `var.allow`, and that inside each block there should be `protocol` and `ports` arguments populated using the corresponding attributes from the elements of `var.allow`. Terraform will then replace this with real `allow` blocks just before passing the configuration to the provider for validation/planning:

```
  allow {
    protocol = "tcp"
    ports    = ["80"]
  }
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your clarifications. It is a great answer.